# Google Authentication: Request optional permissions upon signup?

Tags: authentication, google-authentication

Can I request an optional permission with google authentication?

First I request basic permissions:

```
url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=profile&response_type=code&redirect_uri=my_site.com/g_step2&client_id=CLIENT_ID
```

What works for Facebook authentication, is that the redirect_url calls a function that requests the extra permissions (email). So this would be, for Google equivalent:

```
url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=email&response_type=code&redirect_uri=my_site.com/g_final&client_id=CLIENT_ID
```

For Facebook, regardless of the user's response, this redirects to g_final (the second redirect_uri). Here I either do or do not have access to email.

However, Google treats these at two separate requests. If the user denies the email request, then it's all over. The redirect_uri is not called.

I suppose that I can ask the user beforehand and, based on his response, ask for either basic or both permissions, but it would be nice if there was a way to have this be a natural part of the google authentication flow.